# How can I construct the Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

My question is: How can I construct the Cartan subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra L which is the direct sum of simple Lie algebras, such as for example su(2)⊕su(2)⊕su(2)?

Comment: *A* (not the) Cartan subalgebra in such a direct sum may be taken to be just a sum of Cartan subalgebras in each summand.